# NSManagedObject: isUpdated and isInserted

Tags: iphone, nsmanagedobject

I keep track of my 'objects' using the isUpdated instance method of NSManagedObject Class.

When I'm modifying an exisiting object, it works.

If I create a new object using for example:

```
[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]
```

I can't use the isUpdated, I have to use the isInserted.

This works, but what I want to check, if the object has been modified with *new* data.

isInserted will return FALSE no matter if the object has been changed or not, it only take care if has been inserted or not ...

what can I use ? I can track the initial state of the object properties but I would prefer the isUpdated approach.

thanks!!!

r.

Answer (score 17):

I'm not sure i completely understand your question, however, if you want to check whether your working with an unsaved *new* NSManagedObject, you can do that by writing a small category for NSManagedObject:

```
@interface NSManagedObject(Utility)

/**
 Returns YES if this managed object is new and has not yet been saved in the persistent store.
 */
- (BOOL)isNew;

@end

@implementation NSManagedObject(Utility)

- (BOOL)isNew {
    NSDictionary *vals = [self committedValuesForKeys:nil];
    return [vals count] == 0;
}

@end
```

If you've created a new managed object using:

```
[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]
```

You can use the `-isNew` method to check whether it has been saved or not.

Answer (score 1):

isInserted indicates if the object is "new" (newly inserted to NSManagedObjectContext). I think what You need is method hasChanges (it's on NSManagedObject and also on NSManagedObjectContext)...

```
BOOL someChangeHappendToObject = [myObject hasChanges];
```

checkout [NSManagedObject hasChanges documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1506654-haschanges)